# Can I make the menu label to appear in 2 lines (instead of1 line)

Tags: android

In Android, is it possible for me to make the menu label to appear in 2 lines, instead of just 1 line? I have tried putting '\n' as the line breaker, but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is part of the design spec, I believe.  You just have to make it long enough.  Ideally, since you cannot be certain of the Pixel Density of the device your app is running on, you want to let the OS handle it.  I assume you are talking about the menu bar that is raised when the user hits their hardware button